# H.264+AAC in MP4 muxing bug: Plays OK in VLC but Quicktime is silent

Tags: audio, mp4, quicktime, aac

I'm working on MP4 muxing software that takes input from a hardware H.264 encoder and AAC-LC encoder. The file I produce plays OK in VLC, but audio is silent in Quicktime or when loading into Sony Vegas. If I "convert" the file through VLC to another .mp4, or use Handbrake to convert it, then audio works in Quicktime or Vegas from the resulting file.

[Here is an example file I produced (8MB, 5 sec) which demonstrates the problem.](http://www.filedropper.com/shortrdfrecwithaudio_1)

I'm picking through mp4 headers at the moment playing spot-the-difference but not coming up with much.
Any clues on debugging this, useful analysis utilities etc, would be welcome.

Comment: If you can play the Audio file after demuxing it from the mp4 file generated by your muxer, then it could possibly be an Audio-Video time sync anomaly. I have frequently observed different behavior with different players in case of A-V out of sync. Are you putting the sample durations in the sample duration box properly? What happened in my case was that I was calculating video sample dura. based on 30 fps whereas actually it should be done based on 29.97 fps.

Comment: If you still need help I am interested to look at the file but I can't download it anymore. Got some experience with MP4 since I am the author of mp4parser.googlecode.com